# How to restrict forceful browsing for resources (js,html,pdf,css,images)

Tags: security, jsp, web

This question is might be redundant, but I am not getting concrete answer while searching many reference.

I am having project with below structure.

```
MyProject
    -JavaResources
    - build
    - src
         - main
               - java
               - resources
               - webApp
                       - META-INF
                       - resources
                       - WEB-INF
                                - jsps
```

In this project struture I am having resources (js, css,images,pdf,html) in context root (webApp) folder but out side of WEB-INF.

In jsp I am getting resource with context root path as below:

```
<a href="<%=request.getContextPath()%>resources/Help.html" target="_blank"> </a>
```

Due to this resources can be directly acceesed by browser with context root path and leading to forceful browsing.

One reference I found is application MyProject\src\main\java\resources folder. Which eventually goes in to WEB-INF/classes folder 
But as per servlet specification

> /WEB-INF/classes/* directory for servlet and utility classes. The
>   classes in this directory are used by the application class loader to
>   load classes from.

So I am not sure is this right place for resources or not.

I want to know about best practices and place location to have all type of resources (css,js,html,pdf,css) in web application which can restrict forceful browsing and way to access them in jsp.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `src/main/resources` folder is the standard Maven folder to put resources that must be readable by the application code itself, using the ClassLoader. For example:

```
InputStream in = MyClass.class.getResourceAsStream("/someFile.properties");
```

Once the app is built by Maven, files under src/main/resources will end up being in the `WEB-INF/classes` directory f the webapp.

It is not meant to place files that must be downloaded by the browser. Those files can be anywhere under the webapp root folder, except in WEB-INF.

Comment: Thanks for reply, I am using application.getResourceAsStream("/Help.html") and getClass.getResourceAsStream("/Help.html") both not working here is code <a href="<%= getClass().getResourceAsStream("/Help.html") %>
       target="_blank"> </a> Am I m doing something wrong?

Comment: `getResourceAsStream()` allows, from your java code, to read data from a file in the classpath. Why would you use it to generate a link in a JSP? It doesn't make any sense. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Its an Image link, on click of image an html page will be opened in new tab.Due to security concerns I am able to put it inside context root and outside of WEB-INF. That's why I decided to put in resources folder so it can not be accessed directly.

Comment: The HTML file should be somewhere under the webapp root, and the link should point to it. Don't put the HTML file under src/main/resources. That's not where it should be.

Comment: If html is in webapp root then it can be accesses directly. To restrict direct access and forceful browsing (That is original question) I want to place in resources folder.That's what suggested in ur answer too. Correct me if i m wrong.

Comment: You want it to be accessed by the browser, since you have a link pointing at it. Define "forceful browsing". It doesn't mean anything to me. Are you trying to limit the access to this file only to authenticated users? Or only to some of the authenticated users?

Comment: for html I want to restrict it authenticated users only (can be achieved via security constraints also), and js files as it has some business logic I don't want to make it public ally accessible. So that I have placed them in  src/main/resources ...so that It will be available to in web-inf/classes folder ..but for js files also I am not able to load in jsp files.

Comment: As The flow of the page loading is as follows: the browser sends a request to the servlet; the servlet forwards internally to the JSP, and the JSP is rendered as a response; then the browser parses the <script> tag and fires another request to the script. If the script is not accessible via URL, it's not loaded. So I am not getting how to load js from WEB-INF/classes folder in JSP.

Comment: To be able to be used by the browser, the JS file must be downloaded by the browser. You can't restrict access to a JS file.

Comment: Thanks for ur reply, just to conclude All resources (images,html,js) must be outside of web-inf and under root path so that it can accessed by browser,

Answer (score 0):

web resources are accessed through a GET request made by browser to be used in pages.

from a web server point of view there is no difference if a web resource is requested directly by the user with a browser url or by a page declaring it, ie `<javascript src="some/resource.js"/>`

normal practice is to put resources in a public folder, at the root of web app (exactly what you have done)

if you want to limit access to resources use a `security-constraint` so that only authenticated users can acces them.

if you really want to limit access to resources to be requested only from other pages, maybe you can build a `Filter` and serve them only if `referrer` header is a webapp page.